# REST api design - how to manage related resources and images?

Tags: api, rest

I'm working on a rest api and I have to resources - `news reports` and `report images`. A news report can have many accompanying images. We can't have a repot without an image. On the front end I would like to have one form that allows adding zero or more images along with the report.

I thought of the following URIs:

- GET /api/news-reports/{id}
- GET /api/news-reports/{id}/images
- POST /api/news-reports
- POST /api/news-reports/images

My issue is that I want to upload the images while the user is filling the form, but I can't create images before the news report has been created.

Should I upload the images first with another uri (say: /report-images/upload) and then store the image URLs in a session until the form has been submitted ? Wouldn't  that violate the statelessness of REST ? any better solutions ?

Comment: One solution could be to have a news report 'id' available when the form is shown, so all the uploaded images will be already related by 'id' to the news report created when the user will submit the form.
So think to have an hidden field in the form with a pre-generated id.

Comment: Does that I have to create a row in the news articles table with default data initially ?  What if the user decides to not submit the form?

Comment: You have the same problem with pre-saving the images. What if the user doen't submit the form but you have posted the images already? Think about a clean-up procedure that remove pending images and delete pending rows. Anyway this is only a solution, not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like both the image and the report to go up at the same time, you can use the [`multipart/related`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2387) MIME type when `POST`ing your report. It's officially part of the [IANA registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#multipart).